# Delete virtual directory from VBScript WMI on IIS 7

Tags: iis, iis-7, vbscript, wmi

Using the following winmgmt:

`Set WebAdminWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:root\WebAdministration")`
`Set VDirWMI = WebAdminWMI.Get("VirtualDirectory")`

How do I delete a specific virtual directory by Path and SiteName?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`Delete_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393771.aspx) method

```
VDirWMI.Delete_
```

Comment: Deletes the whole WMI instrumentation for VDir's. Need to rebuild WMI thereafter :D